# Minimalistic rmdir

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, file-system, linux

In my eyes most of the GNU stuff is bloated and doesn't really fit my view of how a Linux environment should look like.  I have come up with my own minimalist implementation of the GNU Coreutils, but I have not touched C in a long time and my programming style reflects that a little.

rmdir.c is a good representation of it throughout the project:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
void process_path(char *path, bool verbose, bool parents);
int main(int argc, char** args){
    bool verbose = false;
    bool parents = false;

    char c;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, args, "vpr")) != -1){
        switch(c){
            case 'r':
            case 'p': parents = true; break;
            case 'v': verbose = true; break;
            default: return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Proccess each path in the remaining arguments */
    int index;
    for (index = optind; index < argc; index++){
        process_path(args[index], verbose, parents);
    }

    return 0;
}

void remove_dir(char *path, bool verbose){
    int ret = rmdir(path);
    if(verbose){
        if(ret == -1) printf("rmdir: could not remove '%s' %s \n", path, strerror(errno));
        if(ret ==  0) printf("rmdir: removed directory '%s' \n", path);
    }
}

void do_parents(char *path, bool verbose){
    while(1) {
        remove_dir(path, verbose);
        char *p = strrchr(path, '/');
        if(p == NULL) break; 
        *p = '\0';
    }
}

void process_path(char *path, bool verbose, bool parents){
    switch(parents){
        case false: remove_dir(path, verbose); break;
        case  true: do_parents(path, verbose); break;
    }
}
```

Statically linked against musl-libc, the executable is only 18KiB, as opposed to the GNU version 39KiB.

Any ideas on how I can improve the coding style or make things even smaller?

Comment: I need to ask: why? Do you do it for fun/learning? Do you need it for an embedded/space constraint environment and think you can do better than [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net) or [Toybox](http://www.landley.net/toybox/)? I don't want to discourage you or anything, just want to know why you're trying to re-implement something that already has been re-implemented many times.

Comment: I wouldn't call 39KiB bloated... Not on a computer that typically has at least 262144000 KiB of storage.

Comment: In pursuit of purity, you ought to collapse `rmdir` into the `rm` utility, as in [Plan9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/about.html). (C source [here](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/plan9/sys/src/cmd/rm.c).) The same program was ported to Unix-likes in [Plan 9 from User Space](http://swtch.com/plan9port/). (That source is [here](http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/cmd/rm.c).)

Comment: @EmilyL. He didn't say that `rmdir` itself is bloated, but _"most of the GNU stuff"_. But on an embedded system where you sometimes measure the available space is mega- or even kilobytes, 39KiB _are_ quite a lot for this simple tool. Even 18KiB is way more than would be really needed. For comparison: I once did a minimal `mount` with optional `-t` support for an embedded Linux system in assembler: executable is 1152 bytes, help and six error messages included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Style

Minor nitpicking: your style is not 100% consistent.

```
int main(int argc, char** args){
// should be
int main(int argc, char **args){

while(1) {
// should be
while(1){
```

## Pattern

I think this block is very, very unusual.

```
switch(parents){
    case false: remove_dir(path, verbose); break;
    case  true: do_parents(path, verbose); break;
}
```

A `switch` with a bool is the same as:

```
if(parents){
    do_parents(path, verbose);
} else {
    remove_dir(path, verbose);
}
```

## Memory manipulation

```
void do_parents(char *path, bool verbose){
    while(1) {
        remove_dir(path, verbose);
        char *p = strrchr(path, '/');
        if(p == NULL) break; 
        *p = '\0';
    }
}
```

I think this is nasty: it modifies the string pointed to by `path`. Granted, it *is* a `char *` instead of `const char *`, but ultimately you're modifying the string from your `main`s `args` (BTW, the convention is to call that `argv`). I would make a local copy of `path` for that.

That way, you could turn almost all your `char *` into `const char *` (and const is good since it helps find accidental manipulation bugs).

## Standard compliance

What is your `-r` option? Neither my GNU nor my BSD `rmdir` know it. Since you fall through to `-p` they're equivalent so you might be thinking *recursive*? It needs a comment, IMHO.

## Help

If your tool is called with wrong or missing argument, it silently exits. IMHO a good command line tool should always have a help/syntax page.

## Return value from `main`

When you encounter an unsupported option you do:

```
default: return -1;
```

You shouldn't return a negative value from `main` as for POSIX environments, the return (exit) value is just an 8-bit unsigned integer. Values above 125 or 128 are usually treated specially by the shell (marking that it was terminated by a signal). But `-1` in two's complement limited to 8 bits is `1111 1111` = 255. Thus, your shell might think your command got killed.

So instead of `-1` you should return `1`. But *actually*, according to C99, the correct values to use are `return EXIT_FAILURE;` in your `switch` and `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` at the end of your `main`.

## Personal opinion

This is just *my* personal opinion and I know others might not disagree, but here goes: I think an `if` should always have curly braces, except if its body is short and on the same line.

So I think this is OK:

```
if(p == NULL) break;
```

But I think this:

```
if(ret == -1) printf("rmdir: could not remove '%s' %s \n", path, strerror(errno));
```

is too long and thus should be broken into several lines:

```
if(ret == -1){
    printf("rmdir: could not remove '%s' %s \n", path, strerror(errno));
}
```

I think it's a not a good idea to have an `if` and a newline without curly braces: either it's one line or it has to have braces. For reasons, see Apple's `goto fail;`.

## Logic/intention

This is also more on the personal opinion side:

```
if(ret == -1) printf("rmdir: could not remove '%s' %s \n", path, strerror(errno));
if(ret ==  0) printf("rmdir: removed directory '%s' \n", path);
```

Apart from the fact that I think these `if`s should be broken into several lines, I think they should be written as:

```
if(ret == -1){
   printf("rmdir: could not remove '%s' %s \n", path, strerror(errno));
} else {
   printf("rmdir: removed directory '%s' \n", path);
}
```

Either the call to `rmdir` succeeds or it doesn't. Your version doesn't make it clear that this really is an *either/or*.

Comment: Can you please cite this? - "You shouldn't return a negative value from main as for POSIX environments"

Comment: @syb0rg: See [Wikipedia "Exit status"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX). It's a consequence of to the `WEXITSTATUS` macro. See also the POSIX/SUS page for [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html).

Comment: Small correction: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` were introduced in C89, not C99. And if you're rewriting the GNU coreutils, you probably do want to stick to C89. :-)

Answer (score 4):

As `remove_dir()` returns `void`, you are discarding the return status of `rmdir()`. If the verbose flag is not enabled, the program will succeed or fail silently, with no way to distinguish the two other than inspecting the directories that exist afterwards. A failure ought to result in the immediate termination of recursion and a non-zero exit status. If there are messages, I would expect them to go to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Comment: +1 on return value and `stderr`. But since he's using `strerror` he would already get meaningful error messages and using `perror` instead thus isn't necessary, IMHO. But might be the better choice nevertheless.